# Fail in renaming executable files

Tags: linux, ssh

I execute command through ssh in python.

```
os.system("ssh atl.LB99@172.31.54.76 'bash --login -c "if [[ -e filepath && ！ -L filepath ]];then mv filepath filepath.backup; fi;"'")
```

I have a list of file paths doing with this command. The purpose of this scommand is add ".backup" after the origial filename. However, this is not always working. Filenames end with *(which are executable files.* is not a part of filename, it is just saying that this file is a executable file), have not change their name to "filename.backup". And those files do have enough permissions (for example, -rwxrwxr-x).

The system is linux and the shell is bash.

What is the key to solve this?

Comment: The file permissions don't matter. The *directory* permissions matter. That said, using `os.system()` is a really bad idea here in the first place -- you've got three separate shell interpreters without a requisite amount of escaping; a malicious filename could easily run arbitrary commands.

Comment: Also, your `if` doesn't have any `fi` ending it, so it's invalid bash syntax.

Comment: Also, `[[ ! -e filepath && -e filepath ]]` will never be true.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry, those are my typos

Comment: @CharlesDuffy could you make the down votes back if those typos are the reason

Comment: Not my downvote, so no, I can't reverse it. (Trying to counteract *someone else's* downvote with an upvote has unwanted side effects, which is why we have a rule that voting should be on a question or answer's individual merits alone, not based on whether one sees its current score as fair).

Comment: (BTW, making a symlink from a .backup file to the original file doesn't make a lot of sense. Are you sure you didn't want to reverse the order of arguments, and maybe use `cp` rather than `ln` so that the "backup" file still retains its current content even if the non-backup version gets corrupted/modified?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh, i should write mv not ln. i will reply your answer later. Now is not at home.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy i refered a wrong part of my codethanks for reminding that

Answer (score 2):

Without the bugs and incidental complexity, this might look like:

```py
import subprocess
try:
    from pipes import quote # Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    from shlex import quote # Python 3.x

# does not need to be shell-quoted; path='/path/to/filename with spaces' is legal
path = "filepath"

cmd = '''
    path=%(path)s

    # this is all POSIX-compliant syntax below, so we don't need to rely on bash
    if [ ! -L "$path" ] && [ -e "$path" ]; then
        mv -- "${path}" "$path.backup"
    fi
''' % {"path": quote(path)}

subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'atl.LB99@172.31.54.76', cmd])
```

---

What are the key points here?

- The number of shells needs to be kept to a bare minimum, *or* significant effort needs to be used to ensure that paths are safely escaped. In this case, we're going the former route: Because we don't use `os.system()` or the `shell=True` argument to `subprocess.Popen()`, there is no local shell. Because we don't use `bash -c`, there is *only one* remote shell -- the one directly started by ssh, not an additional one started by *that* shell.
- When we *do* substitute a parameterized value (in this case the filename) into a script generated to be run by a shell, we use `shlex.quote()`in Python 3 or `pipes.quote()` in Python 2 to escape it.
- When we're passing a shell script over the wire, we make sure it's correct syntax -- that means, in this case, that the `if` block needs to be ended with a `fi`. http://shellcheck.net/ is a useful resource for such validation.

Comment: 1. The next step after this code needs the result of this line, that is why I use os.system. I want the code operated line by line. To my understanding, subprocess is kind of like a thread, which will probably change the sequence? 2. For bash -c, I force the remote server use bash as the shell to do the commands. 3. for the syntax, it is really the mistake when I coping code from my project here. I don't if my first two points are correct or not. Love to hear your idea

Comment: The key problem is why moving command only works with unexecutable file? Since a part of file have changed their name, it means no syntax error in code and the code do has its power. So why are executable files special?

Comment: You can wait for a subprocess to complete -- look at `subprocess.call()`. They only run in the background when you tell them to. And just because your code looks like it works doesn't mean it's bug-free -- my example here works even with malicious filenames, whereas a malicious filename with your original code could delete files on your system or do any other act of the attacker's choice. And "malicious" filenames don't only happen by intent -- the worst data loss event I've been present for happened by pure chance after a random buffer was dumped into a filename by a bug.

Comment: I *do not believe the claim* that executable files are special, until proven otherwise (by editing a [mcve] into the question). More likely you've got different permissions on the directories where your executables are stored (or they're on filesystems with different mount flags, &c), or are constrained by SELinux labeling or similar.

Comment: ...now, there are some operating systems where you're not allowed to *modify* executables that are in-use, but there's a very specific error message associated with that constraint (not that you've told us anything about what error message is being thrown at all), and it only disallows modification of the content of the file, not its name.